# Why don't more buildings labels floors with integers?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

> Why don't more buildings label floors with integers?

This is a lot less confusing than having terms like "ground floor", "lobby", "basement" and whatnot:

[image]

Comment: Even numbered floors can be confusing... some have the ground floor as 1 but others the first level up is 1...

Comment: That photo is from a sensible country where ground floor is labeled '0'!

Comment: I don't seen anything "sensible" (or even "logical but stupid") about the way the numbered buttons are arranged.

Comment: Most of the general population doesn't start counting from zero, let alone negative numbers. And I thought buildings labelled their basement things like B1, B2, B3, etc.

Comment: is a `-1` one floor down from where you happen to be?

Comment: If you are going to do that, then all floors should be in one column.  2, 1, -1, 0, -2 is how I read that.